# Is it possible to use ActiveX in a Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, activex

After researching for a few days I can't seem to find a definite answer  to this question anywhere on the web. Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Comment: No. And worse, why would you want to? ActiveX is, to all intents and purposes, long dead. If you've got some ActiveX component lurking around, re-write it in a newer technology.

Comment: `ActiveX` is not used nor recommended in today's standards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveX is an old Windows only technology. You can't use it on anything but windows, consequently you can't use it in Xamarin which has to run Android and iOS.

Generally ActiveX should be avoided as it is being phased out in newer versions of Windows . ([Dropped from Windows Store Apps & Internet Explorer in Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)